# How to send FROM name in email in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I am using Laravel with Mailable class for sending emails with HTML content it is sending, but I am receiving mail with an email address, but I need a name. Still, it's not helpful. Can anyone explain where I made a mistake?

```
Mail::html($template,function($message) use($emailid1,$subject,$fromemailname){
    $message->subject($subject);
    $message->from($fromemailname,'TEST');
    $message->to($emailid1);
});
```

I am expecting an email from TEST. I tried to override the mail config, too, but I am still receiving with an email address only.

Comment: `$message->from($fromemailname,'TEST');` - Unsure how this will work, does `$fromemailname` contain a valid e-mail address or a name? Because if it's the latter then you didn't even specify a valid from e-mail address

Comment: i found the problem $fromemailname is being set null

Comment: Unsure why you've accepted the posted answer then. This question should be close-voted as non-reproducible then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `from` method of the `Message` class takes two parameters: the email address and the sender's name. You might have swapped the order of these parameters in your code. Make sure the email address comes first, followed by the name.

```
Mail::html($template, function($message) use($emailid1, $subject, $fromemailname) {
    $message->subject($subject);
    $message->from('email@example.com', $fromemailname); // Replace 'email@example.com' with the actual email address
    $message->to($emailid1);
});
```